# extract hidden links from web page

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy, extract

please check this link https://maroof.sa/businesses.

it is a link for website from which i want to extract links.

for example if you scroll down you would find a name for store "Marwa store"
if you click on this card this will redirect you to the store page

now i need to scrap all the links for stores in the page " https://maroof.sa/businesses "

after inspection i found it hidden

i have successful extract the store name
but i cant find the link

thanks in advance

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy import Selector
import csv
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url="https://maroof.sa/businesses")
html = driver.page_source
names = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR , 'div.storeCard')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to get business details from card info, however, it can be build by getting data from request with url part `business/search` .

Business link can be built by pattern `{url}/details/{id}` where id can be got from response json object `items`.

You can get needed response by using [Chrome Dev Tools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-setAcceptedEncodings) that is now available in Selenium.

Also site has anti-scrapping mechanism, it doesn't load every time for me, so you need to use proxy / Undetected Selenium / etc. I added some stealth chrome options, but it doesn't help every time to avoid bot detection mechanism (site thinks that I'm a bot even in regular browser, so I think their bot detection is broken).

```py
import json
import time

from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.set_capability('goog:loggingPrefs', {'performance': 'ALL'})

def enable_stealth():
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
    options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
    options.add_argument("--enable-cookies")
    options.add_argument('--disable-web-security')
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

enable_stealth()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options)
url = "https://maroof.sa/businesses"
driver.get(url)
logs = driver.get_log("performance")
time.sleep(5)
target_url = 'business/search'

def get_links():
    for log in logs:
        message = log["message"]
        if "Network.responseReceived" not in message:
            continue
        params = json.loads(message)["message"].get("params")
        if params is None:
            continue
        response = params.get("response")
        if response is None or target_url not in response["url"]:
            continue
        body = driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.getResponseBody', {'requestId': params["requestId"]})
        items = json.loads(body['body'])['items']
        for item in items:
            link = f"{url}/details/{item['id']}"
            print(link)

get_links()
```